# Bind action IE_Pressed it doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

The first time you press the button, everything works fine, a single press - the function is called. All other clicks are called only after something like a double click, (press, release, press) and only after the third action the function is called

`InputComponent->BindAction("ActionWithObject", IE_Pressed, this, &ASpectatorPlayerController::OnActionWithObjectPressed);`

Answer (score 1):

Project Settings -> Engine -> Input -> Viewport Properties -> Default Viewport Mouse Capture Mode = Capture Permanently Including Initial Mouse Down

Comment: thank you very much